# Disabling simultaneous rightBarButton / tapGestureRecognizer touch

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `viewController` that makes its `navigationBar` and `statusBar` disappear / reappear when the user taps the screen (much like the photos app). I'm noticing when I push the `rightBarButton` "Done" on the `navigationBar` and tap the screen simultaneously, it makes the bars disappear while the `viewController` is transitioning (thus not displaying any bars on the viewController that gets pushed).

I've tried disabling the `rightBarButton` when the `UITapGestureRecognizer` gets triggered, and also tried disabling the `UITapGestureRecognizer` when the `rightBarButton` gets pushed, but it doesn't make a difference, this only happens when they are pushed simultaneously.

Does anyone know a solution that would prevent this from happening?

Comment: Perhaps ensuring the navbar is made visible in `viewWillDisappear:`.

Comment: Or set exclusiveTouch on the view with the gesture recognizer or on the button :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way it to `setExclusiveTouch:` to the navbar view (and therefore to the `rightBarButton`).
So in you `viewDidLoad`:

```
for (UIView *v in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {
    [v setExclusiveTouch:YES];
}
```

Comment: I don't think exclusive touch will work because it seems to be happening simultaneously

Comment: Yeah I did test, it actually seems to make it a little bit tougher to trigger the bug, but in the end I'm still able to trigger it when I try enough. Thanks though.